# ExoPlayer SCTE-35 AdBreak Implementation example

Tags: android, exoplayer, scte-35

I am working Exoplayer but I need to integrate the Ad break using SCTE-35(Ad-Insertion data by providing access in a user-friendly) Ad break in ExoPlayer.

I need some implementation details.